# Is there a newer Bitcoin blockchain download available?

Tags: bootstrap.dat

The SourceForge project page for Bitcoin provides a blockchain download at http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/blockchain/ but this file is old/dated.

How and where can I download an up to date copy of the Bitcoin block chain?

Comment: I found this http://eu2.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/ but it isn't dated (silly)

Comment: @ColonelPanic that link is broken

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since v0.10, the parallel block download in Bitcoin Core is often comparable in speed to torrent downloading, does not require temporary double storage, and validates while downloading instead of sequentially.

*Original answer:*

Please use the bootstrap.dat torrent download. It is more frequently updated and much safer to use.

You can find the .torrent download at http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/blockchain/bootstrap.dat.torrent/download

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it's safer?

Comment: Because it verifies the blocks on import, instead of trusting someone to give you a pre-validated pre-indexed database.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that the .zip files contained the raw `blk*.dat` files. Thanks.

Comment: My service provider blocks torrent downloads. So this is not a good solution for me. Any other sites?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the complete blockchain at https://flo.sh/bitcoin-qt-bootstrap-dat/

If you follow the steps described the initial startup of Bitcoin-Qt should work significally faster :)

Comment: It's not meaningfully faster post v0.10.

Comment: Probably slower actually, given the double handling of the block data.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go I have recently uploaded the bitcoin blockchain to sourceforge.

Blockchain & Chainstate Date: 29th October 2013

Download Link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoinblockchain/files/29-10-2013/
Download Size: 9GB (Compressed) - 13GB (Decompressed)

Comment: What do you think about using **btsync** to keep a up to date bootstrap.dat file http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html

Comment: Thank you. When download completes, can I rsync it with my ~/.bitcoin directory or is it like this sourceforge link which is rather tricky to decipher http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/blockchain/

Comment: In 2013, the blockchain size was 13 GB. In December 2018, it is 195 GB. This answer is totally outdated. Downloading only 6.5% of it won't help today.

Answer (score -1):

You can "Download the latest snapshot from our high-speed CDN" on http://bitcoin.network but it's not free. It seems to be always up-to-date.